# adhoc queries using opendatasource microsoft.ace.olebd.12.0 reading excel file

Tags: adhoc

adhoc queries using opendatasource microsoft.ace.olebd.12.0 reading excel file

Everthing was working fine on my local even on production for a long time already "months". As long as the user is a sysad.
And then, just all of a sudden the script using OpenDataSource using microsoft.ace.olebd.12.0 raised an error

OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Unspecified error".
Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".

No one is altering the script
No one has updated the server nor my local. 
All of the servers for different apps that uses the script encoutered the error.

I'm really confused already on what happened on the driver? Is this some kind of a expiration on the ace driver??

Hope someone could help me.

Answer (score 1):

Do you still have this issue?
Is it a x32 or a x64 server?
Did you install any windows update?
I get this error using AccessDatabaseEngine_x64 driver, and then just installed the x32 driver (no x64 removal) and it worked just fine. The might be a dll dependency or something. Check if you had any windows update regarding these drivers.

Hope you fixed your problem :D
Regards